# AngularJs 4.x and Firebase auth

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

Now I'm using AngularJs 4.x with Firebase auth and now I'm having a problem with that after a component launched, I could get the user Information.

I don't know what point calling this API,

> https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=xxx

But after a component initialized, I could get the user information. So I can not check the user is logged in or not.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
     if(this.authenticationService.getUser()) {
     }else{
       // false always because this code will be run before calling the getAccountInfo API
     }
  }
}
```

The AuthenticationService looks like this,

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;

    constructor(
        private fb: AngularFireDatabase,
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth

    ) {
        afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
            console.log('state changed', user);
            this.user = user;
        });
    }

    getUser() {
       return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    }

    login() { ... }
```

How can I get user-info first before running any component?

Comment: Why not make getUser return a promise that resolves with the user when ready or null when not.

Comment: @bojeil To get when ready, is it able to watch the class variable changes?